# NFS mount. Permission issue?

Tags: server, mount, permissions, nfs

Attempting to mount an NFS share on my server and the following seems to be as far as I get...  I've tried various solutions apart from an OS reload, which may be coming still... :)  Not running an LDAP server, as each machine has it's own local authentication.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
sudo mount -t nfs -v 192.168.10.4:/Storage /home/david/Storage/
```

***Reults in:***

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon Feb  1 08:27:50 2016
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.10.4,clientaddr=192.168.11.11'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.10.4:/Storage
```

Comment: What are the contents of your `exports` file on the server? What does `showmount -e 192.168.10.4` say when run from the client?

Answer (score 0):

If your `showmount -e` shows you the correct shares, you may have mapped UID/GID incorrectly.

From this [how to page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto):

> ```
> Note regarding UID/GID permissions on NFSv4 without Kerberos
>     To make UID/GUD work as with NFSv3, set sec=sys both in the server's /etc/export and in the client's /etc/fstab. This will make
> ```
>
> NFSv4 work with the old host-based security scheme.
>
> ```
>     They do not work. Can someone please help investigating? Following this guide will result in UID/GID on the export being
> ```
>
> generic despite having same UID on client and server. (According to my
>   experience it works at least with "precise", if uid/gid are equal on
>   both sides. hwehner) Mounting same share on NFSv3 works correctly with
>   regards to UID/GID. Does this need Kerberos to work fully? According
>   to http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1128994 and
>   http://opensolaris.org/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=68381 you need to use
>   Kerberos for the mapping to have any effect.
>
> ```
>     This is a possibly related bug: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=500778
> ```
>
> Not clear what is meant by UID/GID on the export being generic. This
>   guide does not explicitly state that idmapd must also run on the
>   client side, i.e. /etc/default/nfs-common needs the same settings as
>   described in the server section. If idmapd is running the UID/GID are
>   mapped correctly. Check with ps ax|grep rpc that rpc.idmapd is
>   running.

I know that it's not clear but it's the only possible answer that I can give (as I'm also seeking the answer).

EDIT: As stated [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811195/kerberos-and-uid-gid-mapping/81119), Kerberos isn't needed.