# Kerberos and UID/GID mapping

Tags: networking, server, nfs, kerberos

Is Kerberos needed for proper UID/GID mapping for a NFS system?

Comment: I think you are referring to NFS. If so, Kerberos is not needed for that. Make sure the the user on the local and remote servers have the same UID.

Comment: Thank you, can you make that an answer?

Comment: Check the edits in the answer, especially the link to SF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simply mapping the UID/GID while using NFS, you do not need Kerberos. Kerberos will add extra layers of security to NFS but not needed for mere UID/GID mapping.

Also note that, if you are using NFS v.4 you can map username/group name of local/remote servers [using `idmapd`](https://serverfault.com/a/632315/289265) instead of UID/GID mapping of prior versions.